# Mypy showing "Callable... has no attribute "connect" on every connect() in PyQT

Tags: python, pyqt5, mypy

Writing a code using PyQt5, using mypy to find type errors. But mypy finds errors on every connect(), for example on this simple file:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class TestClass(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.accepted.connect(self.accept)
```

I have mypy error: `1.py:6: error: "Callable[[], None]" has no attribute "connect"`

Is there any way to explain mypy it's correct code? I'd like not to use "ignore" comments for him...

Comment: are you sure that [`QtWidgets.QDialog.accepted`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qtforpython-5.12/PySide2/QtWidgets/QDialog.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QDialog.accepted) is not a callable?

Comment: It should be callable, it's a signal which I'm connecting to a slot

Comment: What type stubs are you using for PyQt?  Seems like QDialog should have type stubs that declare `QDialog.accepted` as a `pyqtSignal` rather than a `Callable`.  (Or does your `TestClass` try to "override" the `accepted` attribute as a method?)

Comment: @Samwise how to check my stubs? I didn't override anything, it's a complete code to illustrate the "problem"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the `PyQt5-stubs` type stubs for PyQt5.

```
>mypy test.py
test.py:6: error: "Callable[[], None]" has no attribute "connect"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)

>pip install PyQt5-stubs
Collecting PyQt5-stubs
  Downloading PyQt5_stubs-5.15.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (371 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 371 kB 3.3 MB/s
Installing collected packages: PyQt5-stubs
Successfully installed PyQt5-stubs-5.15.2.0

>mypy test.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```